# Convert datetime to date using a function

Tags: sql-server, function, date, datetime, sql-convert

I have one column in my database that I need to convert from datetime to the date data type using a SQL Server function. I can't figure out how to get the correct syntax. Could I get some help with the syntax so IntelliSense will stop yelling at me and I can get the query to run?

```
CREATE FUNCTION fChangeDateFormat (@date01 date)
RETURNS DATE
AS

RETURN(
SELECT
    Convert(DateTime, OrderDate, 101)
FROM
    Orders
WHERE 
    OrderDate = @date01
)
```

Comment: `CONVERT` is already a function, why do you want to wrap it in another one? Are you looking to permanently alter the datatype of your table column or do the conversion on-the-fly for reporting purposes?

Comment: I need to alter the datatype of the column permanently. What do you mean by on-the-fly?

Comment: You don't need to use a function to alter the column, I would simply add a new column, then run an UPDATE query to populate it, then drop the old column. Just seems like you're over-complicating the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use convert as,

```
select CONVERT(date,@date01,101) as dd from Orders
```

If you are using SQl server 2012 + use FORMAT,
'd' is to get the short date format.

```
SELECT FORMAT(@date01,'d','en-US') as dd from Orders
```